# What is map(&:id) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is not an error, it is for understanding. As I'm new to Rails, I can't read all the code yet.

1. what does `(&:id)` do after `.map`

   ```
   @user_cnae_classifications = user.cnae_classifications.map(&:id)
   ```

   what is the difference of `.map` with it and without it?
2. in this method call:

   ```
   UserCnaeClassification.create(
     user: @user,
     cnae_classification_id: id
   )
   ```

   How do I read that part of the code...

   ```
   user: @user,
   cnae_classification_id: id
   ```

   are they keys and values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 )
You should read some tutorials on `map` to get acquainted.
https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/ruby-map-method

But the short answer is that running `user.cnae_classifications.map(&:id)` will loop over all `cnae_classifications` and extract the `id` from them and put them all into an array. The `&` character allows for `map` shorthand to avoid passing an entire block.

From the link above:
[image: Ruby Map Method Diagram]

2 )
The `#create` method can accept a key-value hash of known attributes (known to the class in question, in this case that is `UserCnaeClassification`) to assign upon creation. So you're basically right, they are key-value pairs but they are specific to this class/object. Those same keys might not work on another class/object.
Additional reading: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create

Answer (score 1):

> 1. what does (&:id) do after .map

The syntax `map(&:method)` is equivalent to:

```
object.map do |i|
   i.method
end
```

The complete explanation is that the `&` operator is used to convert any Ruby object that responds to `to_proc` into a `Proc`, which encapsulates a block of code. In this case, the `Symbol` object (`:id`) is converted into the block of code above.

If you're interested in learning more about it, notice this is *pure Ruby*, not Rails-specific. [Check the documentation for `Proc`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Proc.html).

> 2. In this method call:
>    How do I read that part of the code...
>    are they keys and values?

These are *keyword arguments*. It's a way to name the parameters of a method to explicitly tell the reader what each value should be. Just be aware that the behavior of methods accepting hashes as keyword arguments is deprecated, [as seen in this official post](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/).

Answer (score 0):

The `.map(&:id)` is a shorthand for the longer form  of `.map { |x| x.id }`.

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting things to say: if you're using database (ORM - ActiveRecord), you will see that writing map(&:id) could  be helpful. There also exists method called pluck, which does similiar things, but it's a little faster.

[image]

[image]

Usage:
[image]
Also pluck doesn't work with regular Arrays.

Comment: `pluck` is a Rails enhancement / extension. Using `pluck` on an `ActiveRecord::Association` it is faster then `map` because it reduces the amount of data loaded from the database. Using `pluck` on an enumerable (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck) works only with keys for hashes and not with methods on containing objects.